# MongoDB Connection refused Errno:111

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, parse-platform

I have a problem with Mongo, I edited (/etc/) `mongod.conf` and `mongodb.conf` (bind_ip = 0.0.0.0) etc. ... but everytime when I try to use the mongo shell it tells me "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused " Why is Mongo connecting to 127.0.0.1 ? And I cant also use the command `-ssl ->` Mongo dont know this command line ...

Can anyone help me :/ ?

I use a Linux Server (Ubuntu)
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12

I try to install this to create a parse server for an app.

Answer (score 5):

binding the ip to 0.0.0.0 just means that any connection which comes through on port 27017 will connect either locally or remotely. It is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 because you are connecting to it locally.

I would suggest you see whether mongoDB is listening on this port 27017. by using the command:

```
lsof -i:27017
```

If you do not get any results back, the mongodb may not be running. Run the below to start the service.

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

If this still doesn't work I would suggest to run the following to look at the log file.

```
tail -n200 /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```